# push notifications with FCM doesnt work on all my devices

Tags: swift, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Hi I want to implement push notifications , I have three devices to test it : Iphones 4, 5s , 6 
All of them using IOS 9.3.2 and are registering in my provisioning profile.
 The push notifications work just fine in my Iphone 5s and if my app is in active mode, Im getting the following message in the console when receiving push:

```
%@ [aps: {
    alert =     {
        body = "Jonathan : test me ";
        title = test;
    };
}, gcm.message_id: 0:1470515051789092%8d989dbf8d989dbf]
```

but when I try to get  manage to get push notification in my other device , Im not getting the push in background and when entering my app Im gettting the following message in my console:

```
%@ [from: 199968158838, collapse_key: com.jerem.***********, notification: {
    body = "Jerem :test me ";
    e = 1;
    title = test;
}]
```

I dont succeed in sending them notifications from the Firebase console too,
thanks for your help!

Comment: If the app is backgrounded, the priority needs to be high. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37587311/cannot-receive-notification-in-ios-firebase/38625324#38625324

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen, I try to add priority without success, also that doesnt explain why it is working on my iphone 5s...

Comment: the only thing different between them is the log in the console, are u familiar with the second message in my question? why am I getting the collapse key

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem with iPhone 6s plus (9.3.2). I tested on iPhone 5s and it's working properly. When I tested on Friday, everything work fine.

Comment: I update iPhone to 9.3.3 and nothing change..

Comment: Did you add pod 'Firebase/Messaging' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem with iOS 9.3.2, but when I reinstall my app not working on iPhone 5s too. The problem was with token, so I add this method and is's working:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
    FIRInstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: .Sandbox)
}
```

Remember .Sandbox type is for development mode.