# Most stable FCM plugin for Cordova

Tags: cordova, firebase, cordova-plugins, firebase-cloud-messaging

What is the most stable and functionality-rich FCM plugin for Cordova. All that is needed is receiving push messages and a FCM registration token. Both foreground and background.

I have tried https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm and it does the job for Android but not for iOS as I don't get the js callback. So I am looking for an alternative that would work the SAME on both platforms.

Thanks in advance for answering

Comment: Are you sure that it does not work for IOS?

Comment: @AhmadWabbi I never get the .onNotification(..) callback in iOS

Comment: stable and well maintained https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebasex

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, in my knowledge, there is no better plugin for FCM. Either you try to debug this plugin, or use one of these two (I never tested them):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-firebase

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-fcm-afronutt

Please comment on this if one of them work for you, so that you benefit the others.

[EDIT]
Apparently, the second link is just the same plugin that you use.

[EDIT2]
See [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41303013/cordova-firebase-fcm-plugin-not-showing-notifications-in-notification-bar-on?rq=1) for a possible solution of your problem with cordova-plugin-fcm

[EDIT3]
I use cordova-plugin-fcm for both IOS and Android till today 18/6/2018. It works perfectly fine. I update IOS on my IPhone 5 frequently. So it is up-to-date.

Comment: Thanks.
Thing is, I AM getting the notification. The only problem is in the callback not being called on iOS.

Comment: Apparently, cordova-plugin-firebase works. Give it a try.

Comment: @AhmadWabbi is it working on ios 10 and above?

Comment: @LuckyAngelo I didn't try cordova-plugin-firebase on ios. Sorry. If you give it a try, please post here the results you get.

Comment: i tried it. but the dielog where you register for push notification is not appearing. i have enabled push notification capability

Comment: both crash on splash-screen with ios 10.3.2

Comment: @MaorBane Can you give any details programmatically?

Answer (score 3):

I worked on a fork of [cordova-plugin-firebase - npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-firebase) to provide **FCM notification** service on my app in addition to **phone number verification**. I also tested it on Android and iOS. You can find my fork [at GitHub.](https://github.com/ahmedwahba/cordova-plugin-firebase)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to be able to use push notifications (and the registration token is for that).

I haven't used it myself (yet) but [phonegap push plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push) recently (see [announcement](https://blog.phonegap.com/announcing-phonegap-push-plugin-version-2-0-0-fd165349508f) from August) moved to work through FCM.

The old plugin used to work with GCM and now they migrated it to work with FCM. It supports both Android and iOS and still, if you want, let you use APNS as older plugins used to do.

The project seems to be better documented, with lots of example payloads, detailed options and nuances of each device etc, and is very active (108/1544 watches/stars vs. 58/418, on 2017-11-04) with latest update a few days ago (vs. 5/6 month for cordova-plugin-fcm).

From my impression, phonegap-plugin-push is more widely used...

With that being said, I don't have concrete experience with either - only with the predecessor of phonegap-plugin-push.