# Mobile app using Intel XDK and cordova plugin for Firebase notifications

Tags: android, ios, cordova, intel-xdk

I'm using Intel XDK to create a mobile app. I need my application to receive push notifications using Google Firebase. I tried to use the [cordova-plugin-firebase](https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase) plugin, but it does not work in XDK because it has gradle scripts ... I tried removing these scripts, without success. I also tried using the [cordova-plugin-fcm](https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm) plugin; I was able to remove its gradle scripts and build the app. It runs on the emulator, but neither starts on the device.Can anyone send me some tip about why is my app crashing? Unfortunately I have no error message because app do not start and I really don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

use ionic with firebase on intel xdk

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Keluba, but that is not an option because I developed my app based on JQuery Mobile framework... In fact, the app is ready for production! It used to work with GCM but suddenly stopped and I have to migrate to Firebase, just to make me more clear.

Comment: i use firebase for my web projects alongside angular js but firebase works with plain java script which can be integrated to jquery mobile (used that years ago)

Comment: Read firebase javascript web set up or go for an alternative backendless, backand

Comment: Also check out firecast tutorial on cloud messaging on youtube