# Push Notification FCM doesnt appear when app is in background

Tags: swift, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to implement the FCM Push Notification service  for a chat app, I follow the step in the Firebase doc , Im getting notifications when they are sent from the Firebase console to my device.
When I try to send the notification using my server side to the device through FCM using http post to https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send :

my headers are :

```
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=AIzaSyZ-1u...0GBYzPu7Udno5aA
```

my body is :

```
{ "notification": {
    "title": "Portugal vs. Denmark",
    "text": "5 to 1"
  },
  "to" : "myDeviceRegistrationId"
}
```

When my app is in background , nothing is happening (I repeat myself but with the console, I am getting the notification in background )

When the app is active and I am sending this notification to my device, Im getting the following message in my console Log, So I suppose that I am getting the notification but for some reason its not displaying it in background

```
Message ID: 0:1470132526023119%8d989dbf8d989dbf
        %@ [aps: {
            alert =     {
                body = "5 to 1";
                title = "Portugal vs. Denmark";
            };
        }, gcm.message_id: 0:1470132526023119%8d989dbf8d989dbf]
        2016-08-02 13:08:46.913 ProjectAlpha[13324:4726432] Warning: Application delegate received call to -application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler: but the completion handler was never called.
```

what am I missing ?
thanks for your help..

Comment: have you try with setting priority "high"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38479668/firebase-api-is-not-sending-push-notifications-when-using-the-api/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you active background mode?

[Look this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyLVp.png)

Comment: sometimes there may be a delay in receiving notification.

Comment: Its now working , maybe there was a temporary problem with FCM

Comment: Thanks for this answer @breno!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my issue by deleting the

> FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled

key from **Info.plist** and using

> "content_available": true

to receive messages while application is in background.

Now it works perfectly :)