# how to get registration id from firebase to send notification

Tags: java, php, firebase-cloud-messaging

There is a php code to prepare a bundle for sending notification to firebae :

```
$registrationIds = array( $_GET['id'] );
// prep the bundle
$msg = array
(
    'body'  => $_GET['body'],
    'title'     => $_GET['title'],
    'vibrate'   => 1,
    'sound'     => 1,
);
$fields = array
(
    'registration_ids'  => $registrationIds,
    'notification'          => $msg
);

$headers = array
(
    'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);
```

I want same in java, i did all well and getting response 200 from firebase. 
but i dont know how to get registration-id . As done in php like :

```
$registrationIds = array( $_GET['id'] );
```

Please help me to find out the registration-id.

Comment: on java : `request.getQueryString()` // you will get a=1&b=2 ...etc then split

Comment: Are you looking to [get a query parameter in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=get+query+parameter+in+java)?

Comment: I am trying to access [notification service] (https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message) of firebase as : HTTP POST request

https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=AIzaSyZ-1u...0GBYzPu7Udno5aA

{ "data": {
    "score": "5x1",
    "time": "15:10"
  },
  "to" : "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1..."
}  but i dont how to get "to" parameter for client

Answer (score 1):

**To get the registrationId of a device(iOS or Android) the device needs to send/store it in a DB some where.** I recommend using the realtime database provided by firebase.

- First to get registrationId from the iOS App. Use `let token = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token()`. This Token is known as the **registrationId**
- Take this token and store it in your DB.
- Server side you need to get that token out of your DB and place it as the value for the `registration_ids` or as the value for the "to" key. That should be it.

### What about the "to"

So it's well laid out on how to use "to" in this [StackoverflowPost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38479668/firebase-api-is-not-sending-push-notifications-when-using-the-api)

You don't get the "to" parameter from the client.