# Firebase push notifications swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

So I'm trying to implement push notifications to my app using Firebase, the problem is that the push comes and I receive this message :

> [AnyHashable("id_entity"): 18, AnyHashable("icon"): , AnyHashable("click_action"): offer, AnyHashable("body"):  test by almotech, AnyHashable("from"): 1054934643579, AnyHashable("title"): Test Push Notification, AnyHashable("subject"): offer]

But it does not come on the iPhone, nothing shows up not on background neither on foreground, nothing at all. Any help?

Below is the code I've used:

```
var window: UIWindow?
 let gcmMessageIDKey = "gcm.message_id"
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    //UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = myGreenColor
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = myGreenColor
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.white]
    UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
    //UP Screen when keyboard appear.
    IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().enable = true
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    //MARK:-Push Notifications
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        let authOptions : UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: {_,_ in })

        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
        FIRMessaging.messaging().remoteMessageDelegate = self
        //application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    } else {
        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
            UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        //application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    // [END register_for_notifications]
    FIRApp.configure()

    // [START add_token_refresh_observer]
    // Add observer for InstanceID token refresh callback.
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                           selector: #selector(self.tokenRefreshNotification),
                                           name: .firInstanceIDTokenRefresh,
                                           object: nil)
    // [END add_token_refresh_observer]
    return true
}


// [START receive_message]
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
    // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
    // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
    // TODO: Handle data of notification
    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }

    // Print full message.
    print(userInfo)
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                 fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
    // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
    // TODO: Handle data of notification
    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }

    // Print full message.
    print(userInfo)

    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
}
// [END receive_message]

// [START refresh_token]
func tokenRefreshNotification(_ notification: Notification) {
    if let refreshedToken = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token() {
        Persistence.setMobileUuid(refreshedToken)
        print("InstanceID token: \(refreshedToken)")
    }
    // Connect to FCM since connection may have failed when attempted before having a token.
    connectToFcm()
}
// [END refresh_token]





// [START connect_to_fcm]
func connectToFcm() {
    // Won't connect since there is no token
    guard FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token() != nil else {
        return
    }

    // Disconnect previous FCM connection if it exists.
    FIRMessaging.messaging().disconnect()

    FIRMessaging.messaging().connect { (error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("Unable to connect with FCM. \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")")
        } else {
            print("Connected to FCM.")
        }
    }
}



// [END connect_to_fcm]
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
    print("Unable to register for remote notifications: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}


func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    FIRMessaging.messaging().disconnect()
    print("Disconnected from FCM.")

}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    connectToFcm()
    refresh_Token()
}

func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}

// Refresh User Token
func refresh_Token(){
    if let rememberToken = Persistence.getRemember_token(), rememberToken != "" {
        ApiManager().Remember_Me(remember_token: rememberToken){ (success) -> () in
            if success {
                print("Rifreskimi i token u be me sukses")
            }
        }
    }
}



}

// [START ios_10_message_handling]
@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

// Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
internal func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                     willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                     withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }

    // Print full message.
    print(userInfo)

    // Change this to your preferred presentation option
    completionHandler([])
}

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }

    // Print full message.
    print(userInfo)

    completionHandler()
}
}
// [END ios_10_message_handling]
// [START ios_10_data_message_handling]
extension AppDelegate : FIRMessagingDelegate {
// Receive data message on iOS 10 devices while app is in the foreground.
func applicationReceivedRemoteMessage(_ remoteMessage: FIRMessagingRemoteMessage) {
    print(remoteMessage.appData)
}
}
// [END ios_10_data_message_handling]
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you please update your question with relevant code?

Comment: Thank you, I added the code with the question.

Comment: is push notification send from backend and not firebase console?

Comment: Yes it is sent from backend

Comment: then payload may be wrong .. check this .. might help u http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38479668/firebase-api-is-not-sending-push-notifications-when-using-the-api?rq=1

Comment: The payload is okay. The notification comes but it shows up only in console and only if the app is in foreground. If I set the app on background and try to send an notification nothing comes neither on notifications neither in console. When I open the app on foreground the notification comes in console.

Comment: @Stephanie if it only works in foreground then you got it partially right. You need MUST have 'Remote Notifications' enabled in your Xcode capabilities under **background modes**. Also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42275060/what-is-difference-between-remote-notification-and-silent-notification-in-ios/42302369#42302369). About when app is in background: if you want to get notified upon arrival of notification then you MUST also set `content-available:1`. But it you only want a callback after you tapped then there is no need to set `content-available:1` as tapping on it would

Comment: Give you a callback through : [`userNotificationCenter(_:didReceive:withCompletionHandler:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenterdelegate/1649501-usernotificationcenter)

Comment: @Stephanie Hey have solved your issue? If yes, then update it...

Answer (score 1):

try replacing your app delegate with this , works for me

```
import UIKit
import UserNotifications
import Firebase
import FirebaseInstanceID
import FirebaseMessaging

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    let gcmMessageIDKey = "gcm.message_id"
    let spm = SharedPref()

    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        // Register for remote notifications. This shows a permission dialog on first run, to
        // show the dialog at a more appropriate time move this registration accordingly.
        // [START register_for_notifications]



        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                options: authOptions,
                completionHandler: {_, _ in })

            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
            // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
            FIRMessaging.messaging().remoteMessageDelegate = self

        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

        // [END register_for_notifications]
        FIRApp.configure()

        // [START add_token_refresh_observer]
        // Add observer for InstanceID token refresh callback.
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(self.tokenRefreshNotification),
                                               name: .firInstanceIDTokenRefresh,
                                               object: nil)
        // [END add_token_refresh_observer]
        return true
    }

    // [START receive_message]
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
        // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
        // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
        // TODO: Handle data of notification
        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.
        print("ccc\(userInfo)")
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                     fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
        // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
        // TODO: Handle data of notification
        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.
        print("ddd\(userInfo)")

        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
    }
    // [END receive_message]
    // [START refresh_token]
    func tokenRefreshNotification(_ notification: Notification) {
        if let refreshedToken = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token() {

            print("InstanceID token: \(refreshedToken)")


            spm.setFcmToken(password: refreshedToken)

        }

        // Connect to FCM since connection may have failed when attempted before having a token.
        connectToFcm()
    }
    // [END refresh_token]
    // [START connect_to_fcm]
    func connectToFcm() {
        // Won't connect since there is no token
        guard FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token() != nil else {
            return;
        }

        // Disconnect previous FCM connection if it exists.
        FIRMessaging.messaging().disconnect()

        FIRMessaging.messaging().connect { (error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("Unable to connect with FCM. \(error)")
            } else {
                print("Connected to FCM.")
            }
        }
    }
    // [END connect_to_fcm]
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        print("Unable to register for remote notifications: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    // This function is added here only for debugging purposes, and can be removed if swizzling is enabled.
    // If swizzling is disabled then this function must be implemented so that the APNs token can be paired to
    // the InstanceID token.
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        print("APNs token retrieved: \(deviceToken)")

        // With swizzling disabled you must set the APNs token here.
        // FIRInstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType.sandbox)
    }

    // [START connect_on_active]
    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        connectToFcm()
    }
    // [END connect_on_active]
    // [START disconnect_from_fcm]
    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        FIRMessaging.messaging().disconnect()
        print("Disconnected from FCM.")
    }
    // [END disconnect_from_fcm]
}

// [START ios_10_message_handling]
@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.
        print("aaa\(userInfo)")

        // Change this to your preferred presentation option
        completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
    }
    //when we click on notificaiton
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.
        print("bbb\(userInfo)")
        //
        //Code to be executed when you click notification

        //
        completionHandler()
    }
}
// [END ios_10_message_handling]
// [START ios_10_data_message_handling]
extension AppDelegate : FIRMessagingDelegate {
    // Receive data message on iOS 10 devices while app is in the foreground.
    func applicationReceivedRemoteMessage(_ remoteMessage: FIRMessagingRemoteMessage) {
        print(remoteMessage.appData)
    }
}
```

Comment: nope this doesn't work in my case, I tried it but nothing

Answer (score 0):

## I implemented code in Swift 4:

**

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseInstanceID
import FirebaseMessaging
import UserNotifications

  @UIApplicationMain
  class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, MessagingDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?
let gcmMessageIDKey = "gcm.message_id"

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 80.0/255.0, green: 151.0/255.0, blue: 199.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.white]
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    //MARK:-Push Notifications
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        let authOptions : UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: {_,_ in })

        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        //application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    } else {
        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
            UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        //application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    // [END register_for_notifications]
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    return true
}


 @objc func tokenRefreshNotification(_ notification: Notification) {
    if let refreshedToken = InstanceID.instanceID().token() {
        print("InstanceID token: \(refreshedToken)")
    }
    // Connect to FCM since connection may have failed when attempted before having a token.
    ConnectToFCM()
}
func ConnectToFCM() {
    Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel = true
    if let token = InstanceID.instanceID().token() {
        // print("#########################################")
        print("DCS: " + token)

        //MARK: Save Device Token in UserDefaults
        UserDefaults.standard.set(token, forKey: "deviceToken") //setObject
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    }
}

func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didRefreshRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
    // print("#########################################")
    //print("didRefreshRegistrationToken")
    ConnectToFCM()
}

func application(application: UIApplication,  didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject],  fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    print("Recived: \(userInfo)")
    completionHandler(.newData)
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    // print("#########################################")
    // print("didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken")

    Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken

    // print(Messaging.messaging().apnsToken ?? "No apnsToken")
    // print(InstanceID.instanceID().token() ?? "No instanceID token")
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
    // print("#########################################")
    // print("didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError")
}

@available(iOS 10.0, *)
 public func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Swift.Void){
    let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
    // Print message ID.
    print("Message ID: \(userInfo["gcm.message_id"]!)")
    // Print full message.
    print("%@", userInfo)
}

@available(iOS 10.0, *)
public func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Swift.Void){
    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
    // Print message ID.
    print("Message ID: \(userInfo["gcm.message_id"]!)")
    // Print full message.
    print("%@", userInfo)
}

// [START receive_message]
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
    // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
    // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
    // TODO: Handle data of notification
    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }

    // Print full message.
    //print(userInfo)
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                 fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
    // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
    // TODO: Handle data of notification
    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }
    // Print full message.
    //print(userInfo)
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
}
func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel = false
    //print("Disconnected from FCM.")
}
func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    ConnectToFCM()
}**
```